# OpenCV works with threads but not with processes

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, multiprocessing

Hi everyone and thanks for the help.
I've got this function to save a video from frames taken by my webcam.

```
import cv2
import multiprocessing
import threading
def rec():
    # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret==True:
            out.write(frame)
        else:
            break

    # Release everything if job is finished
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If i use it with threads, and so with this code, it works well:

```
s1 = threading.Thread(target=rec)
s1.start()
```

But if i want to start another process, using the following code, when i open the video it contains only black frames with some noise.

```
s1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=rec)
s1.start()
```

I searched all around but couldn't find any solution.

Also, i'm using Python 3.6

Comment: are you really trying to write into the same file using multiple processes or am I reading your question wrong?

Comment: You are reading it wrong :) i want a subprocess of the main one that handles the recording while the main one does other things

Comment: Should i use subprocess instead  of multiprocessing?

Comment: I tried using subprocess instead of multiprocessing, i've got the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

where is `cap` defined ? Try defining that in the function that you give to multiprocessing. If it is defined in the parent and is passed from the parent to the child, it is being pickled and that probably makes it unusable.

Comment: Not working even if i define it inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem.
I was calling `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` in my main and also in one of my imported modules, and that conflicted. I solved by calling it once.